# Possible consequences of profile picture baring same name as username

Tags: image-uploading

It seems convenient for me to save a user's profile picture using the username of the user as the picture file name. The profile pictures will reside in a folder outside the web root.

I considered this option because it will be faster to display a picture, since a logged in user's username will be stored in a session variable; as against either querying the database for the picture file name every time I need to display the picture or carrying about the picture file name in a session variable for availability. (NB: I only accept JPEG picture files)

What are the possible consequences of using the username as profile picture file name instead of a random or auto generated file name?

Comment: And username is/must be unique, no empty spaces or special chars are allowed?

Comment: @nevermind Yes, username MUST be unique and no empty spaces or special characters are allowed.